# Play mediaplayer song from longlistselector

Tags: c#, windows-phone, media-player, playlist, longlistselector

I'm building an music application for Windows Phone and I've made a playlist displayed in a `longlistselector`. I want to be able to press a specific song from that playlist and play it with the Mediaplayer.

I'm using the `SelectionChanged` method to do this. I've tried different things like:

```
MediaPlayer.Play(llsPlaylist.SelectedItem as Song);
```

And

```
Song song = llsPlaylist.SelectedItem as Song;

        foreach (var number in library.Songs)
        {
            if(number.Name.Contains(song.Name))
            {
                MediaPlayer.Play(number);
            }
        }
```

But I keep getting a `NullReferenceException` because song is empty.

How do I use `llsPlaylist.SelectedItem` to play a song with the Mediaplayer?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code that you load the list with? Also when using the as operator you should check if song is null or not to avoid NullReferenceExceptions. This is something that i just do now every time i use 'as'

Comment: debug your code and check of what type is the object referenced by `SelectedItem` actually. Or change your code to : `MediaPlayer.Play((Song)llsPlaylist.SelectedItem);` that will make situation clear if you cast object of wrong type

Comment: The error I get when I use: `MediaPlayer.Play((Song)llsPlaylist.SelectedItem);`
Is:
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Pitch.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Playlist' to type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song'.

So llsPlaylist.SelectedItem cannot be "converted" to Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song.

Comment: I found the solution!

Instead of directly trying to play the SelectedItem, I'm checking if the Name/Title of the SelectedItem is the same as the name of the song in the MediaLibrary. I'm doing this with two foreach statements. It's a bit of detour, but it's working.
Here's the code:
`foreach (Playlist element in source){
if (element == llsPlaylist.SelectedItem)
{
foreach (var song in library.Songs)
{
if(song.Name == element.Title)
{
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
MediaPlayer.Play(song);
PlayStateIsPlaying();
}
}    
}
}`

Comment: To me this seems like you're binding a collection of playlist objects to the list and not a collection of songs. There is def a better way to do this, but without more of the code who knows what it is